# Ocaml Error with returning a List option type

Tags: ocaml

I've been struggling to get this code to return a `((int * int) list)` option.
It takes two lists of integers and combines them into a list of pairs of ints.

```
let rec safe_zip (ls1: int list) (ls2: int list) : ((int * int) list) option =
  match (ls1, ls2) with
    | ([],[]) -> None
    | ([],_) -> None
    | (_,[]) -> None
    | (h1::t1, h2::t2) -> 
       Some (List.append [(h1,h2)] (safe_zip (t1 t2)))
```

However the `(safe_zip (t1 t1))` is showing an error saying

```
This expression has type int list -> (int * int) list option 
but an expression was expected of type (int * int) list`
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For OCaml, your life would be simpler if you used tuareg, merlin and ocp-indent because it provides informations while writing your code and automatically indent it. I edited your question to properly indent your code because it was a bit hard to read as is.

Comment: And for correctness, follow the last tip from @Jeffrey Scofield. Very important tip.

Comment: It's a minor nitpick, but I find parens are just noise, so `((int * int) list) option` is the same as `(int * int) list option`. Of course, there's also no need to specify the types as specifically as you have, but that may be a requirement for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this call:

```
safe_zip (t1 t2)
```

is passing one parameter to `safe_zip`. But `safe_zip` takes two parameters.

Function calls in OCaml are denoted just by putting expressions next to each other. The parameters aren't parenthesized.

For example, to append two lists:

```
List.append [1; 2] [3; 4]
```

Note there are no parentheses around the two parameters.

Second, note that `safe_zip` doesn't return a list. It returns a `list option`. So you can't just append its result to another list.